# Visibility of multiple background images

Tags: css

How can I set `visibility:hidden` for only one of my multiple background images in CSS?

```
.app1 {
    background-image: url(../img/photo1.png), 
                      url(../img/photo2.png);
    background-size: 17em, 27em;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do `visible:hidden` that on multiple backgrounds you can hide the whole div. One hack I did was to use the background size to get to it

```
/*CSS */
.app1 {
    background-image: url(../img/photo1.png), 
                      url(../img/photo2.png);
}

//JS
$('.app1').css({'background-size':'0 0, 27em'});//to hide photo1.png
$('.app1').css({'background-size':'17em, 0 0'});//to hide photo2.png
```

This is the way to do it till we have some more background specs coming up ;)

Answer (score 2):

As Toni has said `visibility: hidden` wouldn't work.  However if you want to make it so that the image does not show up, you could use the `background-size`, and just make it `0em`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

CSS properties apply fully to the selector that they are written in, so both background images will be affected by `visibility: hidden;` (just as they are both affected by the `background-size` declaration.

You could however nest two HTML elements within each other, then apply a background image to each and add visibility hidden to either of them as necessary.